# Sending data from Arduino Bluetooth

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth

I want to send some data (int) to android app, I can do it by writing text in Serial, but I need to send int from code. All I get is "?". I'm not sure what type of data SerialBT.write should I use.
Here is my code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  SerialBT.begin("ESP32test"); //Bluetooth device name
  Serial.println("The device started, now you can pair it with bluetooth!");
}

void loop() {
  
  RawValue = analogRead(15);
Voltage = (RawValue / 4096.0) * 3300; // Gets you mV
Amps = ((Voltage - ACSoffset) / mVperAmp); 
OdczytNap= analogRead(2);
napiecie=OdczytNap*(3300/4096.0);
napiecie=map(OdczytNap,0,1023,0,5);

    SerialBT.write(napiecie);
    SerialBT.write(Amps);

  if (SerialBT.available()) {
    Serial.write(SerialBT.read());
  }
  delay(20);
}
```

Comment: `SerialBT.write` works differently than `Serial.print`for example. Printing to the serial console actually does a conversion from your value to a readable string. Writing to SerialBT does write the actual value in binary form, not as string. For example: If you read a voltage of 24V and write `24` to SerialBT the other side also receives the value 24. Depending on the implementation on your mobile phone the 24 most likely gets converted to the ASCII character with the value 24 which is a control character and would explain your `?`.

Comment: I assume that sending a value of 65 to SerialBT would lead to you receiving `A` on your mobile device

Comment: Even after changing `SerialBT.write`to `SerialBT.print` you need something to separate the two numbers.